# Red stronger than green?

Tags: color

Is it just me or is the red color stronger than the green? If red is stronger, why? Is there a tool to use a color and convert it to another color with the same strength?

I use `color: green;` and `color: red;`.

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be green/red?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, in your example the red is "stronger".

I believe that what you are perceiving as "stronger" implies having more lightness. If you take Photoshop and use [LAB color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) to adjust only the Lightness, you can give both colors the same Lightness value.

- Green Lightness adapted to default Red lightness:

[image: Green adapted]

- Red Lightness adapted to default Green lightness:

[image: Red adapted]

---

[Lab color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) (emphasis mine):

> Unlike the RGB and CMYK color models, Lab color is designed to approximate human vision. It aspires to perceptual uniformity, and **its L component closely matches human perception of lightness**, although it does not take the Helmholtz–Kohlrausch effect into account. Thus, it can be used to make accurate color balance corrections by modifying output curves in the a and b components, or to adjust the lightness contrast using the L component.

Comment: This is the answer: either the HTML consortium or the browser programmers have not made any effort to "match" the colors, so it is "a green" not "the Green." etc

Comment: @Yorik Actually, while the Red is rgb(255,0,0), the Green is rgb(0,128,0) and the Lime is rgb(0,255,0). [CSS colors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp)

Comment: Right, that's what I said. And to be clear: "this is the answer"= "Alvaro's answer is correct."

Comment: @Yorik That is what I understood, thank you :) I was just adding some information relevant to your comment :)

Comment: @Yorik, the named [web colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors) are derived from the [X11 colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names), which are completely unstandardized: back in 1989, when the list was created, simply getting a computer to produce 140 distinct colors was often a major feat.  There's no point in trying to do any sort of perceptual matching when your designer is using a flat-gamma full-color SGI display, but the end-user has a 16-color EGA display with a gamma of 2.8.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the info. But I still think the X11 color Green (rgb(0,255,0)) matches with the W3C Lime and not the W3C Green (rgb(0,128,0)). Is this correct? Do you know why would this be?

Comment: @Mark its true that it want important then. However we are trying to meove to a color managed world, eventually. So change has to happen sometime. And all the things that were not so important years ago may become todays low hanging fruits.

Answer (score 2):

Like posted above, red is a warm color that advances. The use of color is also dependent on context and the primary user's mental model. If you have to objects of equal size the red object will draw more attention than the green with a neutral background.

Answer (score 1):

It is not strong or weak. As you know visible light is a spectrum of VIBGYOR of which red is last in order which is near to infra red rays whose wavelength makes red color to travel more distance i.e., which makes it standout of the rest. This is the same reason why red light is used to stop vehicles at signals as it is quick attention grabbing because it stands out.

if you want something pleasing, soothing go for lighter shades of orange or yellow. ultimately this is what you obtain on decreasing the strength in red color.

Comment: That's certainly some words.

Answer (score -2):

**Red** is associated with energy strength, power, courage, leadership, determination as well as passion, desire, and love. Red is a very emotionally intense color, people have a strong reaction to it, it enhances human metabolism, increases respiration rate, and raises blood pressure.

**Green** is the color of nature and safety.
It symbolizes growth, harmony, freshness, hope and fertility. Green has a strong emotional correspondence with safety. Dark green is also commonly associated with money stability and endurance. Green has a great healing power, it is the most restful color for the human eye.

> Is there a tool to use a color and convert it to another color with
>   the same strength

First of all what do you mean by same strength ? strength probably is not the right word since it is completely depends on individuals perception towards that color, whether it is strong or not.

But there are lot of tools to create palettes based on other color parameters like hue, saturation, brightness etc.

Comment: Please site where you're quoting from. Plagiarism is not okay.

Comment: I think you have really misinterpreted the intent of the OP.  The second sentence in the question (the one you quoted) clarifies that s/he was not asking about the cultural/psychological meanings of different colors, but was asking about the *value* of the colors (*value* here is used in the context of color theory).  Even with your misinterpretation, however, your answer could have been helpful if you had provided suggestions or examples of the tools that you reference in your final paragraph.

Comment: @ZachSaucier from here: http://www.color-wheel-pro.com/color-meaning.html

Comment: @ZachSaucier I know Plagiarism is not okay. but my intent was to just let him know what those colors mean. I am not asking for a dollar here. [http://www.plat4m.com/blog/using-color-psychology-in-design](http://www.plat4m.com/blog/using-color-psychology-in-design) don't accuse these guys for Plagiarism.

Comment: Regardless of what money you make, plagiarism is still not okay.

Comment: I have my lawyer. thanks for your insights. :D